# Google Now places a notification in my tray for weather and commute times - can I make it do the same for reminders?

Tags: notifications, google-now

I've noticed that Google does a great job of providing me with relevent information depending on where I am and the time of day. I can go to the Google Now page and I can see relevent reminders, information regarding upcoming bills/movies/etc (fetched from my Gmail), traffic and weather information, and much more.

However, I've noticed that only the traffic and weather cards appear in my notification tray - for everything else I have to manually go to the Google Now screen and check the cards that are available at the current time.

To me, this makes a lot of the Google Now features a little useless. As an example, I tell Google Now to "remind me to buy some milk when I arrive at the supermarket." It registers this reminder correctly, but when I arrive a the supermarket I don't actually get a notification of any kind. If I unlock my phone and go to the Google Now screen, I can see the reminder there. But this doesn't help me when I am at the super market.

To make it worse, the reminder **only shows itself when I am at the location**. So, if I don't check Google Now after leaving the supermarket, it won't appear on my Google Now page because - well - I am not at the supermarket. I won't even know that I forgot the milk, because there is nothing on my device to show me that I missed a reminder when I was at the supermarket.

Long story short - I would like to see the reminders (and other Google Now cards - like bill reminders) appear in my notification tray. Is this possible?

This is the notification I see:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/whJwC.png

But if I go to Google Now, we can see that there is other, more important things that it could be telling me about. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUvAT.png

Edit:

Interestingly, if I 'snooze' the reminder for 10 minutes, in 10 minutes time I get an actual notification on my phone telling me to do the thing. Ofcourse this is not much of a solution, because it still means I have to manually look at Google Now to check for reminders.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, after "snoozing" one of the reminders via the Google Now page (essentially forcing it notify me in 10 minutes), the notifications for all other reminders started working again too.

I've tested both location based reminders and time based reminders. Seems like I inadvertantly switched something "on" by forcing one of my existing reminders to snooze for 10 minutes.